# terraform error can some body help me out of this but iam providing valid tokens in the keys file

Tags: jenkins, terraform

```
terraform plan -var-file=uservar.tfvars

[0m[1mRefreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...[0m
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.
[0m
[31mError refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.aws: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    status code: 403, request id: 39888d7e-b3f1-11e7-b6d2-9b6dc0727868[0m[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please spend a few minutes at least formatting your question properly - the console colour codes just won't work here.  As for your error - it looks like your log is perhaps coming from Jenkins - does the jenkins process have access to the keys file you're talking about?

Comment: terraform plan -var-file=uservar.tfvars
[0m[1mRefreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...[0m
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.
[0m
[31mError refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

Comment: provider.aws: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
 status code: 403, request id: 0233adf0-b3f5-11e7-b07e-91b6232311b5[0m[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: i was unable to find what the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `terraform init` first, then `terraform plan`

Go through this document first: [terraform Command: init](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/init.html)

Secondly, for error `The security token included in the request is invalid.`, please go through [aws configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/) to make sure you have set the AWS security token properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got resolution for this one. 
Do you pull your code form Git? If yes, pull only once

Note: Code on Git does not have access_key and secret_key, so if your jenkins job contains source control for every build the values (access_key and secret_key) are overridden. 
-> Pull the code only once 
-> In your jenkins/workspaces, set your access_key and secret_Key (or you can also mention it in Jenkins Build)

Before executing Jenkins job, Set aws cli parameters
aws configure 
Set access_key, secret_key & region

and then execute
terraform init
terraform plan -var-file=uservar.tfvars